# Zookeeper data folder is always empty

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Can someone help me understanding on why my zookeeper_data folder is empty?

I have solr installed in 3 nodes with 1 zookeeper, I did make sure the zoo.cfg has proper configuration for both dataDir and dataLogDir and that's not pointed to /tmp/

I do see files coming into the version-2 folder of zookeeper_log but there are no files in the dataDir version-2 folder. Want to understand in which case this happens.

Note: When I have zoo ensemble in other environments with more than 1 zoo, its then persisting files inside the data folder too.

Thanks,

Comment: The permission might be different between owner of zookeeper process and dataDir.

Answer (score 0):

After installing zookeeper data directory is empty. Work with zookeeper to save some data. For example:

```
bin/zkCli.sh
create /test testdata
```

If there is an error in create command, read error and solve it, if not check the directory folder.